# Can I work out Vs of a saturated transistor with just the resistance of the resistor and the bulb? What would happen if I decrease R?

Tags: transistors

[image: The resistance is 200 Ohms and bulb is 4 Ohms]

I know that I_c will be approximately equal to I_e but given I do not have more information I don't think it is possible to work out the voltage of the source??

Comment: What does this mean: `source voltage of a saturated transistor`

Comment: Do you mean: "What voltage is Vs?". That cannot be deduced with the given information. Decreasing R will increase B-E current, which is a waste if the transistor is already saturated as you state.

Comment: Hint: you should know or assume the gain of the transistor at saturation (like 10 or more) and it's Vbe at saturation (like 0.6V). Then from the current Ic, you can compute the (minimum) Ib then the (maximum) R. Notice that the resistance of a light bulb typically increases markedly when it's lit.

Comment: Yes I do mean what voltage is Vs, sorry about the misinformation

Comment: No, you can't. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not enough data. But lets try anyway

Important charateristic here is dc gain of the transistor. For cheap and powerful transistor it could be anywhere 10-100, lets assume 30.

If resistor value is 30 times more than bulb, then most voltage drop will appear on the bulb. If source voltage is 10 V, then bulb will drop 9 V and transistor 1 V.

If resistor value to bulb resistance is more than gain, for example transistor's gain is 30 and resistor to bulb ratio is 60, then voltage drop on transistor and the bulb will be the same. If source is 10v, then 5v on transistor and 5v on bulb.

You could also get some info from reducing the resistor to lower value, so that resistor to bulb resistance is lower than gain. Then transistor voltage drop will not depend on source almost at all, and will depend on current and transistor size. Something like 0.7 V for 1 A, 1V for 10 A, 2V for 100 A. It depends a lot on a particular transistor.